# Undefined control sequence in matplotlib's pgf ouptut

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am including a `pgf` figure create by matplotlib. I get the following error while building the document with lualatex.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.55 ...,right,bottom]{\color{textcolor}\setmainfont
                                                  {Liberation Mono}\rmfamily...
```

The full line 55 is pasted below.

```
\pgftext[x=1.578628in,y=5.846758in,right,bottom]{\color{textcolor}\setmainfont{Liberation Mono}\rmfamily\fontsize{36.000000}{43.200000}\selectfont \(\displaystyle \displaystyle \frac{dC_T}{dr}\)}%
```

My latex document is as follows, with items in my preamble recommended in the pgf file created by matplotlib.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{import}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVuSerif.ttf}[Path=\detokenize{/home/nikos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/}]
\setsansfont{DejaVuSans.ttf}[Path=\detokenize{/home/nikos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/}]
\setmonofont{DejaVuSansMono.ttf}[Path=\detokenize{/home/nikos/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/}]
\makeatletter\@ifpackageloaded{underscore}{}{\usepackage[strings]{underscore}}\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\input{c5_ct-polar.pgf}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am not very familiar with `pgf`, I cannot tell which part of line 55 is causing the error, but if I comment out all lines with `\pgftext` the document compiles just fine.

The essential part of the `pgf` file is provided below.

```
% this lines works
\pgftext[x=1.578628in,y=5.846758in,right,bottom]{hi}
% When the command \setmainfont is added, the error occurs
%\pgftext[x=1.578628in,y=5.846758in,right,bottom]{\setmainfont{Liberation Mono}hi}%
```

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{import}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVuSerif.ttf}
\setsansfont{DejaVuSans.ttf}
\setmonofont{DejaVuSansMono.ttf}
\makeatletter\@ifpackageloaded{underscore}{}{\usepackage[strings]{underscore}}\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\input{c5_ct-polar.pgf}
\pgftext[x=1.578628in,y=5.846758in,right,bottom]{\color{textcolor}\setmainfont{Liberation Mono}\rmfamily\fontsize{36.000000}{43.200000}\selectfont \(\displaystyle \displaystyle \frac{dC_T}{dr}\)}%

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setmainfont` is defined by `fontspec`

Comment: I have `fontspec` included in the preamble. Do I need to add a preamble to the `pgf` file as well. Since I am using `input`, should the `pgf` inherit the preamble in the main tex file.

Comment: Please strip the `pgf` file of everything that is not needed to demonstrate the error, and then post the contents. As you and David say: according to the code you show, `\setmainfont` should be defined. So something must happen in the `pgf` file ...

Comment: I get `! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color \`textcolor'.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.19 ...y=5.846758in,right,bottom]{\color{textcolor}
                                                  \setmainfont{Liberation Mo...

? ` as you have not defined that color

Comment: I did not get that error, but I simplified the `pgf` file and edited it into the answer. I removed the color from the file, as well as some other options, to focus on the the `\setmainfont` part of the error.

Comment: I haven't worked too much with importing fonts, but I believe I have found the source of the problem. I forgot that the main font cannot simply be set without first defining it. I guess I assumed the `pgf` file would created "ready to use", but now I see that was an unreasonable expectation when using local fonts.

Comment: Your example has local paths so can't be used, I added a version at the end but it only gives the xcolor error, please edit it to show the error in the question

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the `undefined control sequence` was not the command `\setmainfont` itself, but the fact that the font `Liberation Mono` was not defined.

Comment: how can you get an undefined command error? Please fix the example in your question to generate the error, and show how to fix it here